# Determining whether a large building should be split into multiple scenes

Tags: unity, performance, scene

This is about designing a first person retro game in Unity3d. In this game the player would walk around inside a large maze-like building that has corridors on 10-15 different floors.

Each floor has a corridor that is set up as a square that surrounds all other corridors (which are set more or less randomly, like a maze) on that particular floor. The length of each side of this surrounding corridor is about 100 steps.

So, considering that this building would have about 10-15 floors constructed like this, the question I wanted to ask is whether it can be included as a single scene?

Or does the answer to this depend also on other factors such as the type of game assets and target devices?

Comment: You will need to have some idea of what is an acceptable load time depending on the target device. Edit: I guess there are also memory constraints.

Comment: Have you tried simply loading it up and seeing how it performs?

Comment: Step 1: Make the game on a good enough machine. Step 2: Test the game on a bad machine. Step 3: Split levels so that the game performs better. Step 4: Go back to Step 2.